# Tabelas e Atributos Estrangeiros SQL

Tags: sql

Boa tarde, eu fiz um código Sql com as seguintes tabelas:

```
create table Bairro(
    cdbairro int not null primary key,
    nmbairro varchar(80) not null
)default charset = utf8;


create table Aluno(
    cdaluno int not null primary key,
    nmaluno varchar(80) not null,
    sexo enum('M', 'F'),
    cdcursocur int,
    cdrua int,
    numeroaluno int not null,
    cdbairro int,
    cdcidade int,
    dtnascimentoaluno varchar(15) not null,

    foreign key (cdcursocur) references CursoCur(cdcursocur),
    foreign key (cdrua) references Rua(cdrua),
    foreign key (cdbairro) references Bairro(cdbairro),
    foreign key (cdcidade) references Cidade(cdcidade)
)default charset = utf8;
```

Em seguida, meu professor requeriu o seguinte item:

> Exiba todos os alunos cujo sexo seja M e o bairro centro.

Gostaria de saber como posso resolver esse item, pois já tentei e não consegui.

Comment: Coloque também o código da sua tentativa para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Vamos lá. Você tem um aluno, e uma aluna. cada um de um sexo, e uma rum bairro você quer o aluno do sexo masculino, e morando no centro. o que você quer desses alunos alem da exigencia ?

Comment: Olá, Lucas. Se a resposta atendeu à sua dúvida, favor aceitá-la.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cdaluno, nmaluno
from Aluno inner join Bairro on Aluno.cdbairro = Bairro.cdbairro
where sexo = 'M' and nmbairro = 'CENTRO'
```